# Scaling a CosmosDB collection - the minimum has increased recently

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I created a couple of CosmosDB collections with the minimum 400 RU/s during my Azure trial.

I was able to scale them up and down on demand, typically between 400 and 5000 RU/s.

I filled one of my collections with lots of test data (I'm currently at approx. 50GB in there), evenly split across 8 partitions (according to the "metrics" view in the portal).

I'm not able to scale the collection down to 400 RU/s anymore. The new minimum is shown as 800 RU/s:

[Screenshot from my portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf8cJ.png)

I suspect that it has something to do with the number of partitions but I wasn't able to find anything about this in the documentation.

This is confusing, my understanding was that the RU/s can be scaled down to 400 at any time.

My goal is to scale down the RU/s as much as possible and I was hoping to be able to get back to 400 RU/s.

Comment: Maybe related to minimum RU per physical partition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have collection level throughput provisioned, the minimum amount of RUs you can allocate is equal to 100 * number of physical partitions. This is because the minimum number of RUs per physical partitions is 100.

400 is by default the minimum because partitioned collection come out of the box with 4 physical partitions.